# Setting environments variables with docker compose when pulling an image

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

if you look at this bit of yml file;

```
 redis-commander:
hostname: redis-commander
image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
restart: always
environment:
  - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
ports:
  - "8082:8081"
```

you can see this image has an environment variable REDIS_HOSTS. If you look at the image in dockerhub, in the file you can see these environments with default values

Based on this information I concluded that you can override these values with a docker-compose.yml file when pulling the image. Is this a correct way of thinking?

cause i tried to create a simple image with apache and php/xdebug. In my docker file i have made an enviroment variable ENV_MACHINE_IP cause the user needs to set a remote_host when pulling the image.

But it will everytime use my default value i have set (127.0.0.1 or whatever)

Did I miss a step?

Comment: did you try it? what happened?

Comment: Its in the question; it pulled the image but doens't set the env i set up in my docker-compose.yml but uses the default i made in the dockerfile.(which is pushed as an image)

Comment: im trying to understand why you need this IP, I don't need anything like that on my docker lamp stack but feel free to have a nose in https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

Comment: I have got env vars in the compose though

Comment: I'd expect that environment variable to get set when you _run_ the container.  Is the `redis-commander` container actually working, and if not, what error do you get?  You mention a PHP application, how does it interact with this container?

Comment: Well its not an error i get, its just that my environment variable doesnt update the one in the image.  The rediscommander is working, with those environment variables. If i look on docker hub the rediscommander dockerfile the default value is production, but i set it on local. That works. but when trying to build my own image with variables it doesn't work. Maybe i'm thinking wrong.

I'm going to try what @delboy1978uk suggested.

Comment: I need to set my xdebug.remote_host in my dockerfile otherwise it will not work

Comment: Roy, I use XDebug in my Docker compose project, but it doesn't need that var, try these settings https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp/blob/master/build/php/xdebug.ini